# Bootstrap v4 beta 2 - New display classes on rows

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I'm migrating my frontend from V4 Alpha 6 to the latest (at the time of writing this) Beta 2 release.

However in one portion of my UI I have some 'row' elements that are hidden via 'hidden-*-down' previously.

With the new [display classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/), is intentional to use something like:

```
...
<div class="row d-none d-md-flex">
...
```

Since rows use 'flex' display normally?
It just feels incorrect doing it this way for some reason.

Cheers

Comment: @ZimSystem - I did take a look at other questions of the sorts, I'm querying whether this is the current best solution due to the recent update done to bootstrap :) In comparison to the cleaner solutions previously, the only way I managed to figure out how to hide a row element was to select the new display utility of the same display type implemented in the row class itself - a little counter intuitive for web designers and developers alike compared to past solutions which have ignored such quirks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the only correct way to do this now.

Shouldn't mess anything up, it just declares flex two times when the elements are visible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, will likely mark it as correct when I can. Seems weird/messy though

Comment: I agree, but this just makes the Bootstrap 4 CSS *a bit* cleaner.